# How to access document library files via a webservice?

Tags: list, document-library, web-services

I've images that are stored in a Sharepoint document library, can these files be accessed using a Sharepoint webservice ? For sharepoint Lists a service is explosed via the '_vti_bin\Lists.acmxs' url, is there something similar for 'document libraries' ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For 2010, use the REST interface http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff798339.aspx

What will you be using to access the list? C#, Javascript ... ?

Some examples

http://weblogs.asp.net/paulballard/archive/2005/05/08/Using-Data-From-SharePoint-2003-Lists.aspx

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/arpans/archive/2007/07/24/sharepoint-web-service-example-grabbing-wiki-content.aspx

http://www.sharepoint-tips.com/2007/02/how-to-use-getlistitems-web-service.html

Comment: It should also be noted that the Soap based web services are officially deprecated in SharePoint 2013 which means they have not added any new features and it is expected to go away in the next version.  It would be best to use the the client OM or REST services going forward for all remote calls.